# Haskell OpengGL window termination

Tags: opengl, haskell, glut

I've been using Haskell with `FunGen` to create a game and found a termination problem. If I close the game window clicking the `X` button , the Haskell console, from which I launched the game, still operates.

This doesnt happen if the game is closed with a ingame feature that leads to `exitWith` succes.

Is there a way I can capture the `X` buttton event on the OpenGL window to terminate the application?

Comment: Have you tried adding `actionOnWindowClose $= MainLoopReturns` to your `main`, before `mainLoop`?

Comment: @Tinctorius Thanks for the reply, but i get an exeption compiling now, `Exeption: user error (unknown GLUT call glutSetOption, check for freeglut)`. I saw you had some similar problem in your posts, have you solved this?

Comment: Apparently you should get a "proper" `glut32.dll` from somewhere (something other than freeglut?), and put it in the search path of your program (same directory as the program should work).

Comment: Can some of this discussion be tuned in to a proper answer?

Comment: I cant seem to find any "proper" version.